# Is it possible to use OAuth1/2LO with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I have a Rails app that currently uses the DocsList API and has a large user-base already authorized with OAuth1.  I also rely heavily on 2-Legged-OAuth.  I know that the Drive SDK supports domain-delegation with OAuth2 (https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation), but I would like to avoid using this for a few reasons 1) I do not wish to have to have my users re-auth, and more importantly, 2) The ruby client is still in alpha (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/)

I know the calendar and contacts APIs will allow you to still use OAuth1 credentials (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)

Additionally, **I AM able to use the DriveSDK using the OAuth1 Playground**.  I was able to call - https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=etag,items(id,title), authorizing with an OAuth1 Token and Token Secret in the OAuth1 Playground.

I'm wondering if there's a way to specify the user in the DriveSDK so that I can begin using it in production without using a client that is still in alpha.

If anyone has any insight, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I am aware that the java clients (`gdata-java-client`, and `google-api-java-client` before OAuth 1 support was dropped) are able to perform the authorization properly against Calendar API v2 and v3. But as you can tell, the official ruby client has very little support (and has dropped oauth1 as well). It is probably not impossible to fix though, although for Drive API it is a little tricky since it was using OAuth2 all along? I would check with the java client first since it has much better documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use OAuth1 with 2LO to access the Drive API.  The method for doing so is the exact same as described in the Calendar Auth page (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

Both the ruby google client and using the regular signet client will work.